# Command Errored out with ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python-3.x, installation, kivy, command-prompt

I tried to install python kivy on windows using
`pip3 install kivy`
I have upgraded setuptools and wheels, but I repeatedly get the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone help me overcome this issue?

Comment: Please Help....

Comment: Maybe you should do as you're told... what does the complete output say?

Comment: Did you install all the requirements as specified in step 2 of the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist)?

Comment: @John Anderson I installed all the requirements.

Comment: I think i found .the problem. @monamona i actually read the full error and it seems like i need to install Microsoft visual C++ buid tools. Thank you for helping me.